# c# - DbContext gets disposed in BackgroundService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, rabbitmq, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have a WebAPI that should also receive messages from RabbitMQ. I used [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/consuming-rabbitmq-messages-in-asp-net-core/) tutorial, because I know that sometimes IIS likes to kill long-running tasks (didn't test it on server yet though, maybe it won't work). I have a service that handles messages that are received via RabbitMQ. First problem I met - I couldn't inject it into `BackgroundService` class, so I used `IServiceScopeFactory`. Now, I have to consume messages from two queues, and as I understood, best practice is to use two channels for this. But the handling is done in one service. BackgroundService:

```
public class ConsumeRabbitMQHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private IConnection _connection;
    private IModel _firstChannel;
    private IModel _secondChannel;
    private RabbitConfigSection _rabbitConfig;
    public IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public ConsumeRabbitMQHostedService(IOptions<RabbitConfigSection> rabbitConfig, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _rabbitConfig = rabbitConfig.Value;
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        InitRabbitMQ();
    }

    private void InitRabbitMQ()
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = _rabbitConfig.HostName, UserName = _rabbitConfig.UserName, Password = _rabbitConfig.Password };

        
        _connection = factory.CreateConnection();

        
        _firstChannel = _connection.CreateModel();

        _firstChannel.ExchangeDeclare(_rabbitConfig.DefaultExchange, ExchangeType.Topic);
        _firstChannel.QueueDeclare(_rabbitConfig.Queues.ConsumeQueues.FirstItemsConsumeQueue, true, false, false, null);
        _firstChannel.QueueBind(_rabbitConfig.Queues.ConsumeQueues.FirstItemsConsumeQueue, _rabbitConfig.DefaultExchange, "*.test.queue", null);
        _firstChannel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);

        _secondChannel = _connection.CreateModel();

        _secondChannel.ExchangeDeclare(_rabbitConfig.DefaultExchange, ExchangeType.Topic);
        _secondChannel.QueueDeclare(_rabbitConfig.Queues.ConsumeQueues.SecondItemsConsumeQueue, true, false, false, null);
        _secondChannel.QueueBind(_rabbitConfig.Queues.ConsumeQueues.SecondItemsConsumeQueue, _rabbitConfig.DefaultExchange, "*.test.queue", null);
        _secondChannel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);

        _connection.ConnectionShutdown += RabbitMQ_ConnectionShutdown;
    }
    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        stoppingToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var firstConsumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_firstChannel);
        var secondConsumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_secondChannel);
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            IIntegrationService scoped = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IIntegrationService>();
            firstConsumer.Received += (ch, ea) =>
            {
                // received message  
                var content = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body.ToArray());

                // handle the received message  
                HandleFirstMessage(content, scoped);
                _firstChannel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);

            };
            firstConsumer.Shutdown += OnConsumerShutdown;
            firstConsumer.Registered += OnConsumerRegistered;
            firstConsumer.Unregistered += OnConsumerUnregistered;
            firstConsumer.ConsumerCancelled += OnConsumerConsumerCancelled;
            _firstChannel.BasicConsume(_rabbitConfig.Queues.ConsumeQueues.FirstItemsConsumeQueue, false, firstConsumer);
        }
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            IIntegrationService scoped = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IIntegrationService>();
            secondConsumer.Received += (ch, ea) =>
            {
                // received message  

                var content = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body.ToArray());

                // handle the received message  
                HandleSecondMessage(content, scoped);
                _secondChannel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
            };


            secondConsumer.Shutdown += OnConsumerShutdown;
            secondConsumer.Registered += OnConsumerRegistered;
            secondConsumer.Unregistered += OnConsumerUnregistered;
            secondConsumer.ConsumerCancelled += OnConsumerConsumerCancelled;

            _secondChannel.BasicConsume(_rabbitConfig.Queues.ConsumeQueues.SecondItemsConsumeQueue, false, secondConsumer);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void HandleFirstMessage(string content, IIntegrationService integrationService)
    {
        List<StockImportDto> dataToImport = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StockImportDto>>(content);
        integrationService.ImportFirst(dataToImport);
    }

    private void HandleSecondMessage(string content, IIntegrationService integrationService)
    {
        List<Import901Data> importData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Import901Data>>(content);
        integrationService.ImportSecond(importData);
    }

    private void OnConsumerConsumerCancelled(object sender, ConsumerEventArgs e) { }
    private void OnConsumerUnregistered(object sender, ConsumerEventArgs e) { }
    private void OnConsumerRegistered(object sender, ConsumerEventArgs e) { }
    private void OnConsumerShutdown(object sender, ShutdownEventArgs e) { }
    private void RabbitMQ_ConnectionShutdown(object sender, ShutdownEventArgs e) { }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        _firstChannel.Close();
        _connection.Close();
        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In service I get

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
> Object name: 'IntegrationDbContext'.'

`DbContext` is injected into `IIntegrationService`. If I understand what's happening, two instances of the service(or even one) share `DbContext`, and when one of them finishes it disposes `DbContext`. I tried not to create two instances (all code inside one `using`), tried making `IIntegrationService` transient, tried doing everything asynchronously (it was initial version, made it synchronous to test) - still same error. What should I do here? And is this the right approach?

**Update 1.** `ConfigureServices` in `Startup`:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var rabbitConfigSection =
            Configuration.GetSection("Rabbit");
        services.Configure<RabbitConfigSection>(rabbitConfigSection);
        services.AddDbContext<SUNDbContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddCors();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = "My API",
                Version = "v1"
            });
        });
        services.AddRabbit(Configuration);
        services.AddHostedService<ConsumeRabbitMQHostedService>();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddTransient<IIntegrationService, IntegrationService>();// it's transient now, same error with scoped
    }
```

Comment: It probably doesn't affect anything, but just because I noticed: you close the first channel on Dispose, but not the second, and then close the connection that is shared.

Comment: Can you also post your Startup code where you build/register the DbContext and IIntegrationService?

Comment: What happens when `scope` is disposed?  What type of teardown occurs for anything created by the scope?

Comment: @Nikki9696, fixed it, still same error

Comment: @DavidL, msdn says that "An IServiceScope controlling the lifetime of the scope. Once this is disposed, any scoped services that have been resolved from the ServiceProvider will also be disposed."

Comment: So following that line of reasoning, if you have a persistent scope that is resolved outside of the context of an individual message, what happens if the scope disposes before a message is handled?  In other words, you need to resolve a separate scope per message that is handled inside of the message handler.

Comment: @DavidL thanks a lot, it worked. I didn't think about that scenario, I thought that DbContext is disposed because of how scoped services work. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: Typically you'd be correct, but in this case you are creating your own scoping which changes the lifetime.  I added an answer.  Glad it helped!

Comment: I still can't fully get it, will read some more. It's weird that something declared inside using block is disposed before that using block is finished

Comment: It can’t be disposed before the using block is finished. In your original code the using block would finish before your message was handled however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact that the outer `scope` created by `_serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope()` is disposed after each using statement, whereas each message is still trying to rely on the now disposed scope and attached context to process the message.

The solution is to create a new scope per message in your message handlers:

```
private void HandleFirstMessage(string content)
{
    using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        IIntegrationService integrationService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IIntegrationService>();
        List<StockImportDto> dataToImport = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StockImportDto>>(content);
        integrationService.ImportFirst(dataToImport);
    }
}
```